# How-to remote display MS Band on PC

Tags: microsoft-band

I would like to show the Microsoft Band display on a PC. For taking screenshots and for presentations. Somewhere I saw a presenter doing this (maybe on Build 2016).

Does a publicly available remote control tool exist?

Answer (score 0):

He was probably using the Band Emulator - Tool - Fake Microsoft Band Emulator - http://peted.azurewebsites.net/fake-microsoft-band/ .  I personally use a inexpensive overhead cam for a lot of photos and such, the ipveo ziggi - http://amzn.to/2bX6tKW .